# How do you get the HTTP Path Info in C?

Tags: c, apache

I have written a C CGI executable, and I want it to be able to retrieve the PATH_INFO from Apache. For example, if I have the compiled C file as /var/www/html/file, and I request http://localhost/file/pathinfo, How do I get the pathinfo portion?

If you have any idea, please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (and a great deal of other information) is available as environment variables.  This shell script, run as a CGI script in your environment, will dump everything you can get at:

```
#! /bin/sh
printf "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"
printenv
```

From your C program, access the variables using `getenv()` as usual.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using getenv("PATH_INFO");

Answer (score 2):

All the [CGI variables](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/http/reference/httpcgivars.html) are stored in the environment.  There you will find a `PATH_INFO` variable.